# JQuery Custom LightBox - Opacity Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building my own jQuery light box but am running into a small issue. The html page has 6 images on it and when one is clicked an overlay is displayed over the whole page with the image in the center.

The issue I am running into is that the animation that controls the light box displaying is not smooth, it produces a sort of outwards in effect and I would like it to all be effected as one. The animation to fade it out works perfectly though, so I am not sure what I am missing ?

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hqsapk5a/

My HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

    <div class="grid">

        <div class="image-thumb-wrapper">
            <img src="img/Casinogames_2MillionBC.jpg" class="image-thumb" />
        </div>

        <div class="image-thumb-wrapper">
            <img src="img/casinogames_7thheaven.jpg" class="image-thumb" />
        </div>

        <div class="image-thumb-wrapper">
            <img src="img/casinogames_10sOrBetter.jpg" class="image-thumb" />
        </div>

        <div class="image-thumb-wrapper">
            <img src="img/casinogames_21BurnBlackjack.jpg" class="image-thumb" />
        </div>

        <div class="image-thumb-wrapper">
            <img src="img/Casinogames_AfterNightFalls.jpg" class="image-thumb" />
        </div>

        <div class="image-thumb-wrapper">
            <img src="img/casinoGames_AllAmerican.jpg" class="image-thumb" />
        </div>                      

    </div>

</div>
<div class="light-box">

    <div class="light-box-overlay">

    </div>
    <div class="light-box-wrapper">
        <img src="" id="light-box-image" />
    </div>
    <a href="" class="light-box-close">x</a>

</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

        $('.image-thumb').click( function() {
            var image = $(this).attr('src');
            $('#light-box-image').attr('src', image);
            $('.light-box').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(100, 1, function() {
                $('.light-box').css('z-index', '2');
            });
        });

    $('.light-box-close').click( function(e) {
        event.preventDefault(e);
        $('.light-box').css('opacity', '1').fadeTo(100, 0, function() {
            $('.light-box').css('z-index', '0');
        }); }); 
});
```

My CSS:

```
.page-wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .grid {
        width: 600px;
        height: 552px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #DFDFDF;
        border: 2px solid #999;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
    }
    .image-thumb-wrapper {
        width: 228px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .image-thumb:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .light-box {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .light-box-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    img#light-box-image {
        z-index: 10;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        background-color: #999;
        padding: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .light-box {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    a.light-box-close {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        position: absolute;
        text-decoration: none;
        right: 10px;
        top: 5px;
    }
    a.light-box-close:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `z-index` of `.light-box` *after* the fade in animation completes which is why you see it display strangely as it jumps in front of the other content.

Change this block:

```
$('.image-thumb').click( function() {
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#light-box-image').attr('src', image);
    $('.light-box').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(100, 1, function() {
        $('.light-box').css('z-index', '2');
    });
});
```

To this:

```
$('.image-thumb').click( function() {
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#light-box-image').attr('src', image);
    $('.light-box').css({'z-index': '2','opacity':'0'}).fadeTo(100, 1);
});
```

DEMO

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hqsapk5a/4/) what you are looking for?

You just have to make `$('.light-box').css('z-index', '2');` before it `fades in`.

What is happening is that you are putting the `z-index: 2` while it `fades in` that's why it acts weird.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on previous answers, beyond changing the z-index in css, try this ...

```
$('.light-box').css('z-index', '2').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500).fadeTo(100, 1);
```

This will give you a much smoother animation; the time can be adjusted higher or lower from the 500ms.

Comment: Why would you use animate and fadeTo? They both do the same thing?